# In object-c, how to solve The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format of http service

Tags: ios, android-studio

Here is my error:
[image]

I sent request query to server, but this error occurred again and again.

Comment: It is better to post errors as text rather than images and you should probably remove the username and password from the image.  The error seems to be being produced by your code somewhere where it is parsing the JSON response.  You will need to show the data you have got back from your server and the code that is attempting to parse it and is producing the error

Comment: this error is not from your side. This is from the server side. formate of response is not in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Data should be in a structured form. In JSON format, when you sent request query to the server.

Try to use **Advanced Rest Client** google chrome extension or **Postman** to identify this issue. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat. If your problem has solved. Plz, accept the answer. :)